# How to align CSS animation-delay in with NodeJS delay?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, settimeout

How do I add a preloader when my setTimeout is in NodeJS, below is the code to call the api and set a delay for 10s:

```
function delay(s){
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve,s));
}


async function getXml(){
let ans;
await delay(10000)
const {data} = await axios.get('https://gist.githubusercontent.com/SwayamShah97/a3619c5828ac8ed8085c4ae295a855d9/raw/e4e372552e042bd8bd9e8ab87da93eb030114f86/people.xml');
xml2js.parseString(data, (err, result) => {
    if(err) {
        throw err;
    }
    ans = result
    
});
```

I have tried to add the loader using frontend js like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    const loader = document.querySelector(".loader");
    loader.className += " hidden"; // class "loader hidden"
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="loader">
    <img src="/public/images/coffee-loading.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loader.hidden {
    animation: fadeOut 10s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

How it works is, it waits 10s as it should due to the setTimeout, and then shows the preloader for additional 10s instead of aligning with the delay.

How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: perhaps your `fadeOut` definition is wrong ... what do you see happening that's different from what you expected? `due to the setTimeout` what setTimeout? Why would you want a 20 second delay - makes for a bad user experience, if a website takes 20 seconds to load properly, and at least half of that is intentionally introduced delay, there better be a good reason for it!

Comment: I have edited the code to show the delay function. It is just a mock code and not for any production environment. I am just trying to learn how to show the preloader when a button is clicked and before the data shows up

Comment: great ... but what about the the animation called `fadeOut`

Comment: Added it to the CSS part, edited now

Answer (score 0):

```
animation-delay: 10s;
```

I should note that this is pretty bad in terms of user experience unless you plan on reducing those timers.

Comment: I tried to add this in my CSS, it still loads after the delay period of 10s is over

Comment: I would try messing with all the different timers until you get the look you are going for. Maybe make the fadeOut shorter, the delay shorter, or something along those lines.